# draw elements inside group in SVG using JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I would draw elements inside a group.

```js
svg= document.querySelector('svg')
          const g = document.createElementNS('xmlns', 'g');
          const cir1 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
          const title = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
          title.textContent = 'N° 1111';

          g.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(20,20)');
          cir1.setAttribute('r', '3');
          cir1.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
          cir1.setAttribute('id', 'idtitle');

          svg.appendChild(g);
          g.appendChild(cir1);
          g.appendChild(title);
```

```html
<svg>
</svg>
```

I create the group , I attribute x and y coord using translate method.

But nothing is printed on the screen.

Comment: You need to create the SVG element first: `let svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');  div.appendChild(svg);  svg.appendChild(g);`

Comment: I have Edited my post

Comment: document.createElementNS('xmlns', 'g'); is wrong. 'xmlns' is not the SVG namespace. You get it right in subsequent lines.

Comment: Thanks that's it